# How  to remove UI selectmenu in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The code below sets a select menu with UI selectmenu by

```
$('.anyclass').selectmenu();
```

but the question here is how to **remove** UI selectmenu of **.anyclass**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are talking about this [plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/), you can simple do this

```
$('.anyclass').selectmenu('destroy');
```

Comment: +1 Nice guess on the plugin.. Sure would have been helpful if that was posted in the question!

Answer (score 3):

You can remove an element by:

```
$('.anyclass').remove();
```

To remove a particular class:

```
$('.anyclass').removeClass('addedClass');  // where addedClass is something a plugin would add
```

To change a css attribute:

```
$('.anyclass').css('color', 'blue');
```

Comment: No, UI selectmenu generate a customized style for the select menu with (anyclass) class .. I need to remove this style not the (.anyclass) element itself .. it means that I need to remove the UI selectmenu effect

Answer (score 1):

UI Selectmenu creates an imitation of the button and menu for the select box and hides the actual select tag. There's no such thing as removing the styling in this case. All you can do is get rid of the imitation select box and display the actual select tag.

If the select tag has an id of `foo`, then the imitation button and menu have an id of `foo-button` and `foo-menu`, respectively.

```
$('#foo-button').remove();   // or .hide()
$('#foo-menu').remove();     // or .hide()
$('#foo').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use the above linked version of the plugin as its totally outdated and has lots (!) of issues.

Please use https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu/ui (jQuery UI stable) or https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu (jQuery UI dev)